# oracle sql convert mix datetype in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am required to use only one query to convert all "11/19/15 6:18:00 PM" like format to "11/19/2015" in date column (Oracle sql syntax). Can anyone help me with that?

Date Column:

```
12/22/2016
01/17/2017
11/19/15 6:18:00 PM
5/14/13 8:38:00 PM
```

Comment: Hint:  `trunc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me what I want:

```
select to_char(TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(date, '[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+'),'MM/DD/YY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" from table1 where length(date)>10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( date_column ) AS (
  SELECT '12/22/2016'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/17/2017'           FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '11/19/15 6:18:00 PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5/14/13 8:38:00 PM'  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( date_column, '^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( date_column, '^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2} [01]?\d:[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d [AP]M$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
       END AS date_value
FROM   your_table;
```

**Output**:

```
DATE_VALUE
-------------------
2016-12-22 00:00:00
2017-01-17 00:00:00
2015-11-19 18:18:00
2013-05-14 20:38:00
```

*(Note: my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` - this determines how dates are formatted in my session.)*